# Need way to authenticate Mobile Device

Tags: asp.net, mobile, verification, email-validation

All --
       We recently received a contract to develop a mobile ASP.Net version of our web application but one of the requirements is that the user be required to enter a PIN the first time the application is used sort of like how most mobile banking applications work.

I have did some Google search on the matter but I keep on getting links on the Mobile Device Detection and Redirection.

Each user's pedigree information including their email address are entered into a User Store so I would be able to send out a PIN etc to the user's email address for them to enter into their Mobile browser but is this the best way to design this feature?

Are there any ways of identifying the mobile device other than having the user enter in manually?

Thanks!

Comment: What value do you get from knowing the connection's underlying network?  What exactly is it you're trying to do?  Authenticate a user (principal) based on some credentials OR identify the user's underlying network?  I don't see how they are related.

Comment: I am trying to set up some sort of two step authentication but I need help getting pointed in the right direction.

Comment: No worries Mark, thanks for you support, I guess there are idiots every where!

Comment: You hit the nail on the head there. There are some very brilliant people on this site who stand ready to help you in anyway they can so don't let the little people get you down!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a [link](http://www.keyvan.ms/how-to-implement-2steps-verification-in-asp-net-mvc) that I found regarding Two Step Authentication but it is using MVC.

Answer (score 0):

When consumer is browsing through wap proxy (or APN), normaly carriers can identify consumers. So you could use some kind of aggregator like Bango, or Ericsson IPX for consumer identification. If your target countries are few, you could analyze HTTP headers for finding consumer identificators. Here [two](http://mobiforge.com/developing/blog/useful-x-headers) [links](http://certificateerror.blogspot.com/search?q=operators%20http) to starting.

But I think consumer identification is more difficult on WIFI, "internet" APN or other proxies like Opera Mini or Blackberries.

Comment: Thanks for your response, this application will be used by people in the filed to query information from a backend database.